# pserve not working inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, pyramid

I am trying to develop pyramid application with using docker-container.I build a docker images with below docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN  apt-get -y update
RUN  apt-get -y install python3.6 python3.6-dev libssl-dev wget git python3-pip libmysqlclient-dev
WORKDIR /application
COPY . /application
RUN pip3 install -e .
EXPOSE 6543
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    ports:
      - 6543:6543
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-development
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    command: pserve development.ini --reload
```

The docker image is created successfully. But when i run the d**ocker-compose up** and browse the url **localhost:6543** it is showing ***The site can't be reached now***. But when i run it locally with **pserve development.ini** it is working fine. I tried to connect to the docker interactively and run the command pserve develpment.ini, It is showing as

```
Starting server in PID 18.
Serving on http://localhost:6543
```

But when i browse the url from chrome it is not working.

Comment: Are you able to reach the server within container, i.e., with `localhost:6543`?

Comment: How can i test that within the container. ?

Comment: `exec` in the container and run a `curl` command. Check if you're getting a response.

Comment: I am running the server the pserve. So, Is there anyway that i can run the pserve in background.because then only i can run another command on the container console. @shub

Comment: After the `docker run` command you can find the running container using `docker ps` and then you can exec into it to issue other commands, like `docker exec -it <container_name> <command_to_execute>`

Comment: Yes ..! It is responding inside the docker container. @Shubham

Comment: I'd love to understand why this got downvoted. Seems like a perfectly valid, well written question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen in all network interfaces. In your `development.ini` file, use:

```
listen = *:6543
```

You should get a log which says:

```
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:6543
```

Then try to access it from your host machine using `localhost:6543`.